# Failing on install talib in windows 7

Tags: python, ta-lib

I'm trying to install TALib in Windows, but I'm getting this error:

```
   common.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TA_GetUnstablePeriod referenced in function __pyx_pf_5talib_6common_8_ta_get_unstable_period
    build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\talib\common.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\felipe.ferminiano\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe -u -c 
    "import setuptools, tokenize;
        __file__='c:\\users\\felipe~1.fer\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-kye3ah\\TA-Lib\\setup.py';
        f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
        code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
        f.close();
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
    install --record c:\users\felipe~1.fer\appdata\local\temp\pip-al6w47-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"
failed with error code 1 in c:\users\felipe~1.fer\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kye3ah\TA-Lib\
```

when I run:

```
pip install TA-Lib
```

I already installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is mentioned in the `README` in the repository: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib)

> Sometimes installation will produce build errors like this:
>
> ```
> func.c:256:28: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_libc.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> ```
>
> This typically means that it can't find the underlying TA-Lib library, a dependency which needs to be installed. On Windows, this could be caused by installing the 32-bit binary distribution of the underlying TA-Lib library, but trying to use it with 64-bit Python.

Since your error log contains `amd64` it might well be that the 32bit vs 64bit issue is your actual problem.

The library is only distributed in 32-bit format (the compilation/linking dates are from 2007)

Check issue #11, [GitHub - Issue #11](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/11) for hints on how to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running Anaconda3/python3.5/JupiterNotebook: 
Check your version and download the appropriate binary from: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib

Upload and install:

!pip install TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

Ta-Lib installation requires that you install the binary dependency. This can be easily installed by installing the whl file. This file can be found in this link: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib. You can refer to this blog for detailed steps: https://blog.quantinsti.com/install-ta-lib-python/

I had done a parallel run between ta-lib and other packages and also by using jit compiler. But the results of ta-lib were much better. On the internet, you will find many solutions but installing through whl is the best approach.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just download the .whl file then save it inside your python libraries file and pip install TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl, before that try manually delete any file related to talib

Answer (score -1):

The following steps solved the problem for me:

1. **Step 1**. Goto the following URL and download the .whl file for Windows or Mac : [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib)
2. **Step 2**. Goto Anaconda Command Prompt and type the below :
   C:\Users\UserName> pip install TA_Lib-0.4.21-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
3. **Step 3**. If you do not get any error message then TA-Lib will be successfully installed.

Note: You will have to check your existing python version using below code and then choose the appropriate file in step 1:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```